# I want to give 'edit-link i.e <a>edit</a>' if ans column of table from database is null

Tags: java, jsp, if-statement

I am retrieving answer from ans column by using `jdbc` and showing it into a `jsp` page in a form of a table, if ans column is `null` or empty then I have to give a user edit link, but if ans column has a value then I'm going to show answer but the problem is `if-else` condition is not working. Please help me to solve this, My code is given below:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table center-aligned-table">
        <thead>
        <tr class="text-primary">
            <th>Question No</th>
            <th>Question Name</th>
            <th>Answer:</th>
            <th> </th>
            <th> </th>

            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% 
            try{     
               int oopa=1;
               //String nme=(String)session.getAttribute("vname7");
               DbCon cc=new DbCon();
               Connection onn=cc.fun();
               Statement stt=onn.createStatement();

               ResultSet r=stt.executeQuery("select ques,ans from postquestion;");

                while(r.next()){ 
        %> 

        <tr class="">
            <td><center><%=oopa++%></center></td> 
            <td><%=r.getString(1)%></td> 
            <% 
                if(r.getString(2)==null) 
                {
            %>

            <td><a href="">Edit</a></td> 

            <%
                }
                else
                {   
            %>
            <td><%=r.getString(2)%></td>

            <%  
            }  
            %>

            <td> </td>

        </tr>

            <%

            }
}
            catch(Exception vjin){
                System.out.println("I am vjin: "+vjin);
                vjin.printStackTrace();
            }

            %>

    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the query is executed correctly ?

Comment: @Arhana can you elaborate what is not working ?

Comment: @Swati Hello, if the table consists of answer then i want to display that answer in <td><%=r.getString(2)%></td> which is working but if the table does not have anything then i want to give edit link (which is not working) but i typed there <a>edit</a> still it is not displaying...

Comment: @RandaElBehery Yes query is right, if the condition is false then it is displaying answer in a <td> that's what i want but if the condition is true i.e if the table of a database does not have answer then i want to display edit link in <td> but it is not working..

Answer (score 0):

You might get empty values from your results. So check if r.getString(2) is empty or not, null differs from empty value.

More over, JSP is just a view component, writing DAO code in JSP is not a good practice.

Thanks

Comment: hello, my query is right, I checked it too many times and it is working too cuz it is displaying answer in <td> ,only problem is if the condition is true it should display edit link in <td> which is not working...Please help me with it

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me/share your SQL output. I am interested to see your result shows empty or null for your second column. if it is showing empty, you have to check empty in your JSP if condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `null` values using **[wasNull()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull())** method of `ResultSet`.For example like below :

```
        <% 
         //getting value of column in "a"
            String a =  r.getString(2);
          //checking if resultset return null i.e a is null then do below:
            if(r.wasNull()) 
                {
            %>

            <td><a href="">Edit</a></td> 

            <%
                }
                else
                {   
            %>
            <td><%=r.getString(2)%></td>

            <%  
            }  
            %>
```

Comment: okay, I will try this if it didn't work i'll let you know, thanks.

Comment: No, It is not working, should i check for isEmpty()? , if the ans column of a table is blank,does that mean it is empty or null? , How i m supposed to check if it is blank?if(r.getString(2)==" ") is this right ?

Comment: Try like this-> `if(a == null || a.isEmpty() || a.equals(""))`

Comment: No, It is not working, Is there any problem with the netbeans IDE cuz it is not displaying html tags?

Comment: If problem would be in `html` tag then your `table` might also not display ,but they are displaying .so i don’t think that might be issue. Can you post your `db` image where `ans` value is `null` ?

Comment: ans value is not null ,it is blank, I was wrong and were checking for null value but it is not null

Comment: It is giving me an error,PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method isBlank()
  location: variable a of type java.lang.String ....I never used isBlank() , i don't know anything about it, I'll be back tomorrow , Please help me with this problem

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()) out for more detail.

Comment: I solved this problem with the help of your suggestion to store the value of r.getString(2) in a variable as t=r.getString(2) and i checked as  if(t.equals(" ")) and it worked the problem was i was checking like this if(r.getString(2).equals(" ")) which was wrong ,hence thank you with your help.

Comment: Glad i helped :)